# Importing a data table makes QGIS crash

Tags: query

I try to import a table with around 500.000 entities and it makes my computer load it endlessly then eventually crash. I do the same query with smaller tables and it usually works.

How can I fix this?

[image: Problem]
[image: Problem]

Comment: I don't see any import settings, only an expression for calculating a new field. Please clarify.

Comment: Seems like a hardware issue. You could try dropping unnecessary rows or fields from the table. or truncate it into smaller datasets and loading them separately.

Comment: Is it crashing when the table is imported or when you calculate field values?

Comment: Try doing the update on a subset of the table (select or filter the first 100 000 rows, then update, then repeat for the next 100 000 etc). I personally tend to do large attributes updates with command line tools only

Comment: @GabrielC., Erik, indeed, it's when I try to save the attribute table after executing the query, not when loading the shapefile.

Thank you for your suggestions, JGH, Encomium, I will try to find a workaround since they probably are, just need to get my hands on the software and query issues.